# Group by two of three columns SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, max, teradata

I feel like this should be easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a table of four columns.  Three columns have text descriptions of categories.  The fourth column has a count of how many times a concatenation of the first three columns appear in the original table.

The table looks something like this.

```
Vertical   Cat       Sub-Cat       Counts
Auto      Cars       Sports Cars   9
Auto      Cars       Sedan         20
Auto      SUV        Luxary        21
Auto      SUV        Mid-Range     8
```

The goal is to select the Vertical, Cat, and Sub-Cat for the highest 'counts' of a unique version of vertical and cat.

So, the query would return the following.

```
Vertical   Cat       Sub-Cat       Counts
Auto      Cars       Sedan         20
Auto      SUV        Luxary        21
```

I've tried to using Max() to select the highest 'counts', but I have to group by all values of the non-aggregate groups on TD13.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use old-style SQL with a Correlated Subquery

```
select *
from tab as t1
where counts = 
 ( select max(counts) 
   from tab as t2
   where t1.Vertical = t2.Vertical
     and t1,Cat = t2.Cat
 )
```

Or a multi-column subquery or a join to a Derived Table with a group by, but all should get a similar plan.

The most efficient version (and easiest to write) is usually a Windowed Aggregate Function:

```
select *
from tab
qualify row_number() 
        over (partition by Vertical, Cat 
        order by Counts desc) = 1
```

Comment: +1 for the Windowed Aggregate Function solution. T-SQL only? Had completely forgotten about this approach as have been away from Sql Server for a few years.

Comment: @LongboatHarry: No, QUALIFY is Teradata specific syntax, not SQL Server, but Teradata was tagged :-) In all other DBMSes you need to nest the ROW_NUMBER in a Derived Table and filter using a WHERE in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

1. Form your aggregate query by selecting the maximum Counts, grouping by the fields you want to aggregate - Vertical and Cat
2. Then use the result of that query as a sub query that joins back to the table to select out the other fields you want - Sub-Cat in this case

So something like this pseudo sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT Vertical, Cat, MAX(Counts)
   FROM <table>
   GROUP BY Vertical, Cat
) MY_AGGREGATE
ON MY_AGGREGATE.Vertical = <table>.Vertical 
AND MY_AGGREGATE.Cat = <table>.Cat
AND MY_AGGREGATE.MAX(Counts) = <table>.Counts
```

Comment: AND MY_AGGREGATE.MaxCounts = <table>.Cat